# RPi3 Bluetooth Tethering Setup

Tags: bluetooth, raspbian-buster, bluez

I'm trying to setup automatic Bluetooth Tethering without a GUI, and I can't find anything that works online. A lot of forums just end at the mention of "Blueman."

The only way I could even find to manually tether (without using Blueman) was to use `sudo bt-network -c <MAC> nap`.

There should be a way to setup the config files to auto-tether, right?

CURRENT STATUS: Trying to setup DHCP and auto-tether.